# Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had a table,

```
CREATE TABLE tmpOne(testID INT IDENTITY (1,1), 
ID AS ('ABC'+ (CASE WHEN len(testID) <=3 THEN CAST(RIGHT(0.001*testID, 3) AS VARCHAR) ELSE CAST(testID AS VARCHAR) END))PERSISTED UNIQUE, 
Ename VARCHAR(20))
```

I want to create another table #temptwo with Column PID which refers ID of table #tmpone I did this

```
CREATE TABLE tmptwo(ID VARCHAR FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tmpone(ID))
```

Iam getting error as:-Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale.

How can i get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st table - `CAST(... AS VARCHAR)`
You cast to varchar but you don't specify a length.
The default length is 30 (+'ABC' length)

2nd table - `CREATE TABLE ... (ID VARCHAR ...)`
You declare a varchar column but you don't specify a length.
The default length is 1.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

You should declare lengths on both tables and should not count on defaults. 
In addition, if you'll wrap the whole computed column expression with `cast`/`left` you'll have no surprises.

```
CREATE TABLE tmpOne
(
    testID  INT IDENTITY (1,1)
   ,ID      AS (cast ('ABC'+ (CASE WHEN len(testID) <=3 THEN CAST(RIGHT(0.001*testID, 3) 
                     AS VARCHAR(100)) ELSE CAST(testID AS VARCHAR(100)) END) 
                         as varchar(100))) PERSISTED UNIQUE
   ,Ename   VARCHAR(20)
)


CREATE TABLE tmptwo(ID VARCHAR (100) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tmpone(ID))
```

Comment: tried declaring them as VARCHAR(30) in both the table and still it gives same error

Comment: Because for the first table it is +3  (length of 'ABC')

Comment: Cool I saw his answer first and I seen your edited version later sorry for that...Wonderful explanation thanks Cheers :)

Comment: Good to know Dudu, but you have few more times to edit the answer. Just keep editing....copied well from my answer but still not same ;) and I am not that much hungry for points just welcoming good questions. Always happy

Answer (score 2):

You can't create reference column in temporary table but in physical table you can as by using your code:

--In temp it gives error as "***Skipping FOREIGN KEY constraint '#tmptwo' definition for temporary table. FOREIGN KEY constraints are not enforced on local or global temporary tables.***" but same code with bit change works for physical table:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpOne(testID INT IDENTITY (1,1), 
ID AS 
    CAST(('ABC'+ (CASE WHEN len(testID) <=3 THEN   
        CAST(RIGHT(0.001*testID, 3) AS VARCHAR(20)) 
    ELSE CAST(testID AS VARCHAR(20)) END)) as VARCHAR(50)) PERSISTED UNIQUE, 
Ename VARCHAR(20))

CREATE TABLE tmptwo(ID VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tmpone(ID))
```

I am sure you can identify the changes :)

We have to CAST whole columns value as VARCHAR and define the length for the same and it will be the actual column length which we can define in the reference column of another table.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create Table Table1
(
id int identity(1,1),
User_id as 'ABC'+Right('0000'+cast(id as varchar(20)),20) persisted Unique,
Salary int
);
sp_help Table1  -- here is check Length of User_id & give that length in reference table
create Table Table2
(
id int identity(1,1),
User_id_Table2 varchar(23) foreign key references Table1(User_id),
name varchar(50)
);
```

Comment: How did you isolate this? What is the right version of the SkiaSharp libraries? Without these details, this answer is unlikely to help future readers with a similar problem.